# PHP Academic question: internal calculation

Tags: php

```
echo (int)(3980 / 100 * 50); 
echo PHP_EOL;
echo (3980 / 100 * 50);
```

output

```
1989
1990
```

can someone explain this phenomenal for me?

Comment: `floor(3980 / 100 * 50)` give `1989`. It should be a rounding thing internally.

Comment: but `3980 / 100 * 50` should gave out exact 1990 right?
and why when not rounding is correct

Comment: [This](https://3v4l.org/RX7dO) is a more interesting example, I think. I don’t know what changed in PHP regarding floating point numbers, but I think a standard rule is “don’t rely on the string cast of a float”. The int cast at least makes sense, since PHP rounds towards zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of how floating point numbers are represented internally in binary [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

One may think **(3980 / 100)** will be **39.8**

But infact, it will be represented exactly like **39.799999237060546875** and multiplying it by 50 it will be **1989.999961853**

Now **(int)1989.999961853**.. you guessed it **1989**

Comment: Yes, `(int)` is the same as `floor()` in this case. If this question is meant beyond understanding and there is an actual math error you must fix: [BCMath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) or [PHP-Decimal](http://php-decimal.io/#introduction)